# SAML Artifact Resolution

Tags: federated-identity, openam, federation

I have two Tomcat servers IDP and SP. Created hosted IDP and a fedlet on the IDP. Copied the fedlet.war on to the 2nd tomcat, after creating the fedlet files I copied the keystore as well. When I checked the "Run Fedlet (SP) initiated Single Sign-On using HTTP Artifact binding" it's working fine, but the issue is when I tried the same Artefact resolution through soapUI it doesn't work, it gives an error Unable to find Response corresponding to the Artifact. The following is the request I am attempting 

   
      
         fedlet
         AAQAAKgOz0Mrql9XC/LYEI17oa5EcuzgelQy8/TKGDwHTJMKIgwbSlN+MDE=

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The artifact is for one time use. Make sure that you are not first sending i with Tomcat and the trying i with SOAP UI.

Instead you must catch the Artifact resolve and stop it, then paste it into SOAP UI and send it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to validate the Artefact?

Comment: If this worked for you, you should mark the question as answered and set up a new question regarding the validation